# Efficiently using two-column ranges in SQLite

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have a table of `(start_date, end_date, description)` -- in order to find events that happen within a given period, I am doing

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE start_date < $view_end AND end_date > $view_start
```

This works correctly, and many database products would be able to use an index on both columns to efficiently find the result -- but SQLite only supports using one range index at a time (I can do lots of indexed equals comparisons, but only one indexed greater-than or less-than). As a result, if I want to view the middle 10 events in a table of a million, I can only use one index to eliminate half of them, and have to do a full table scan on the other 500,000.

Are there any cool tricks I can do to rewrite this query in a way that is efficient, given SQLite's limitations?

Answer (score 0):

This wont be as fast as if you could use two indexes but will be much faster than just using a table scan on the second column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE start_date BETWEEN $view_start AND $view_end AND end_date > $view_start
```

It will cut your table scan down to only the records that started between the data range you're looking for (rather than all records that started before your end date)

Comment: The original query includes records that start before $view_start, your query does not.

Comment: @Jeff, I'm well aware that my query is different to the posters, it was based on the assumption that `$view_start` is less than `$view_end` and that `start_date` is less than `end_date`. I feel that is entirely a reasonable assumption unless told otherwise.  Now instead you could have picked up that mine includes records where `start_date = $view_end` which the OP query didn't but it was just done like this for readability, you could easily make it `start_date > $view_start AND start_date < $view_end` instead if you so wish, and it would still use the index correctly.

Comment: This is faster, but yeah, I need events that have /any/ part of themselves between view start and view end :(

Comment: Can you maybe work on an assumption like how old your longest date difference between `start_date` and `end_date`? For example, if your data at most is 2 months old, you can subtract 2 months from `$view_start`.